# No test assemblies found matching the pattern - Visual Studio Test - VSTS

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops

This question is similar to - [VSTS Test Assemblies - No test assemblies found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47288399/vsts-test-assemblies-no-test-assemblies-found) - which appeared to resolve itself at the time. Unfortunately I'm getting a similar recurrence that I'm not sure how to resolve.

During my Visual Studio Test step, I'm getting the following message....

```
2017-12-05T18:43:31.9808980Z ##[warning]No test assemblies found matching the pattern: *SA.SEPA.Web.UI.Selenium.dll.
```

In my VSTS tasks, after I build my solution, I copy an entire project directory to a directory on the virtual machine. This virtual machine is also hosting the build agent.

The path to the test assembly file is here, after the files have been copied....

[image]

My test task looks like the following....

[image]

The search folder should be correct, as this is the machine with the build agent.

Looking at the minimatch patterns described here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/file-matching-patterns, `*SA.SEPA.Web.UI.Selenium.dll` should also match to the `SA.SEPA.Web.UI.Selenium.dll` file, possibly without requiring the asterix (?)

The build log is located here - https://gist.github.com/Konnor5092/1feb4536f7dd92218de27df8f3fefc52

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't the pattern need to be `**\SA.SEPA.Web.UI.Selenium.dll` in order to find it in a subfolder? I'm running on an older version of TFS, but it should be pretty easy for you to try it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your dll is in a sub directory of `c:\build` so the search will need to be recursive:

```
**\SA.SEPA.Web.UI.Selenium.dll
```

or change the search folder to `c:\build\bin\debug`

Comment: Thanks. Yep that's what I was missing